# Remove after .jpg

Tags: regex, razor

I'm getting a value like this:

```
myimage.jpg123456jpg
```

and I need to remove everything after `.jpg`

how can I write this in razor?

Comment: In Razor? Razor is a view engine. You should use some server side language such as C# or VB.NET to achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about razor but this regex would match the part you'd like to save in the first result group:

```
(.+\.jpg)
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2v7ki

Answer (score 0):

Just match on `.+\.jpg`, which will give you the `myimage.jpg` section of the text.